# Updating field by dynamic field name

Tags: elm

I would like to update a field using a dynamic field name.
In my example I have two `div` with `contenteditable` attribute. On `blur` event I need to update the model (each div update its field).

```
module UpdateTest exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Json
import Debug

type alias Model =
    { field1 : String
    , field2 : String
    }

type Msg = Update String String

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }

init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init () =
    ( { field1 = "value 1", field2 = "value2" }, Cmd.none )

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [ contenteditable True, attribute "data-id" "field1", onBlur (Update "field1") ] [ text model.field1 ]
        , div [ contenteditable True, attribute "data-id" "field2", onBlur (Update "field2") ] [ text model.field2 ]
        , div [ id "fiedl11" ] [ text model.field1 ]
        , div [ id "fiedl12" ] [ text model.field2 ]
        ]

onBlur : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onBlur tagger =
    on "blur" (Json.map tagger targetTextContent) 

targetTextContent : Json.Decoder String
targetTextContent =
  Json.at ["target", "textContent"] Json.string

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Update id text ->
            ({model | id = Debug.log id text }, Cmd.none) -- here the issue
```

Do you think there is something better?

EDIT:

I wrote a simpler example than the real one thinking that it would be better to understand the problem. However, the number of fields is very large and grows dynamically through user actions. The structure is really more complicated, the fields can be nested (4 levels), and they are ordered. You can think that it is a model for a text document with sheets, columns, sections and paragraphs (all of these elements with an id).

EDIT 2:
Maybe, It could be more interesting use the path to the field inside the model structure for update its value. Instead of using its id.

Answer (score 5):

Elm is a statically typed language so there isn't a way to refer to a field of a record using a string value as that would cause type errors to occur at runtime.

Elm also lacks any kind of runtime introspection/reflection so you can't get type information at runtime that would allow you to automatically match a string against the field name of a record.

You will need to do the following:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Update id text -> case id of
            "field1" -> ({model | field1 = text }, Cmd.none)
            "field2" -> ({model | field2 = text }, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: thank you. That is not a solution to my problem, because my question is just an example. I really need there to be many divs, and the user can create more

Answer (score 4):

You example doesn't seem to illustrate your actual problem, but from that, our previous conversation and the comment on @Jessta's answer, my guess is that what you actually want is to use a `Dict` to keep track of your fields. If so, first we need to change the model:

```
type alias Model =
    { fields : Dict String String }
```

This uses the `String` id as a key, and has just the text `String` as the value. If you need to keep other information you'll have to replace the last `String` with you field model type.

Then we need to initialize the model. We do so with the same information you had in your example, but now contained in the `Dict`:

```
init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init () =
    ( { fields =
            Dict.fromList
                [ ( "field1", "value1" )
                , ( "field2", "value2" )
                ]
      }
    , Cmd.none
    )
```

Rendering the view is done just by converting the `Dict` to a `List` and then mapping it to `Html` elements:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        (model.fields
            |> Dict.toList
            |> List.map
                (\( id, value ) ->
                    div
                        [ contenteditable True
                        , attribute "data-id" id
                        , onBlur (Update id)
                        ]
                        [ text value ]
                )
        )
```

For brevity I've skipped the two "display" divs as they seemed unnecessary, but adding those at the end just requires doing this again but with a different render function. And if you really need them to be siblings of the `contenteditable`s, just concatenate the two resulting lists of elements.

And lastly, to update the field model we just use `Dict.update` with the `id` and a field updater function:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Update id text ->
            ( { model
                | fields =
                    Dict.update id
                        (\_ -> Just text)
                        model.fields
              }
            , Cmd.none
            )
```

That's it. I hope I've understood the problem well enough for this to be helpful. If not, I guess you'll just have to try explaining it again.